# How to make a button cancel a CountDownTimer - Android app

Tags: android, button, timer

I have a Count down timer with the following code, how can I make a button (i.d button2) stop (or cancel) the timer. but also make it so if the time runs out they are intent'ed to Scores.class.

Timers code:

```
LevelOne context;
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_one);

    context = this;

    new CountDownTimer(1500, 1500) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Scores.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }.start();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't just use "new CountDownTimer" (without instantiating a CountDownTimer object) or else you basically won't have a way to reference it again.

So instead, make an actual CountDownTimer object, e.g.

```
CountDownTimer myCountDownTimerObject = new CountDownTimer(1500, 1500)
{
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    public void onFinish() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Scores.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Notice there I did not include the ".start()". That is because you will call it later e.g. in onCreate, or wherever you want to "start" your timer.

So, in onCreate (for example), write:

```
myCountDownTimerObject.start();
```

Then, inside your onClick for your button, type this:

```
myCountDownTimerObject.cancel();
```

I hope this helps!

***EDIT***

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


    Button myButton;

    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
    {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.intentForYourActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long arg0) {
            //do something
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //ass soon as this activity is created, I start my timer.
        timer.start();

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                timer.cancel();
            }});
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example with the onClick and onCreate methods combined into it?

Comment: Ok, I gave an example.

Comment: The line "myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){" is throwing up an error saying " - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new 
  OnClickListener(){})

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to import android.view.View.OnClickListener. At the top of your file you should just right: import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: I think you could have imported the wrong one. So check the one you have right now, and make sure it is the right one (your problem right now is a common issue). To be on the safe side, you technically can also type "new View.OnClickListener" instead of just "new OnClickListener" INSIDE the setOnClickListener round brackets.

Comment: Thanks. When I did View. etc it corrected it to what you had already and it works now! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem :D But for things like that problem just now, you should just search on StackOverflow, since most of the time, someone has already asked the same question you are asking.